# Angular limitTo does not return proper output

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I guess that the output of the following code should be **text 3** and **text 4**, but not getting the right one. Any problem in code there?

HTML

```
<body ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="t in getTimes(4) | limitTo:-2">text {{$index+1}}</div>
  </body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.name = 'World';
     $scope.getTimes = function(n) {
       return new Array(n);
     };
});
```

Comment: @PirateX  it can be negative too, negative means it starts from the end

Comment: @WildWidow Will `-5` be same as `-2` then?

Comment: @PirateX if the array has 2 elements -2 will be same as -5. If you exceed the length of the array, it will just stop at the first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because you have duplicates in your set and `getTimes()` is retuning `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`.

In this case, use `t in getTimes(4) | limitTo:-2 track by $index` with a proper array initialization or use a function that avoids duplicates.

Another problem is that `$index` always starts by **0**. So you will not get **text 3** and **text 4** as you expect. You would need to use `text {{t}}` if you want the array value.

Examples:

**track by $index**

```js
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.getTimes=function(n){
        return new Array(n);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="t in getTimes(4) | limitTo:-2 track by $index">text {{$index+3}}</div>
</body>
```

**OR**

**sequential array**

```js
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.getTimes = function(n){
        return Array.apply(null, {length: n}).map(Number.call, Number); // [0, 1, ..., n-1]
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="t in getTimes(4) | limitTo: -2">text {{t+1}}</div>
</body>
```

Comment: people expect to read "text 2 , text 3", you can maybe add values in your array and display it, instead of the indexes from the "limited" array for better understanding... I not sure I am clear enought :p

Comment: see this url http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ref_limitto_end  they can print from 4th position and they use limitTo and negative value.

Comment: i got right output here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/hLkky28n/ i am getting right output if we populate array in advance.

Comment: tell me what is difference between below two line

`<div ng-repeat="t in [1,2,3,4] | limitTo:-2 track by $index">text {{t}}</div>

and

<div ng-repeat="t in getTimes(4) | limitTo:-2 track by $index">text {{$index+1}} </div>` ?

Comment: The first your are using `{{t}}` and the second `{{$index+1}}`. With `{{t}}` you get the array value. With `{{$index+1}}` you get the array index + 1. Another difference is that your `getTimes(4)` returns `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]` instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: I've fixed my answer. `getTimes(4)` returns `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]` instead of `[4, 4, 4, 4]`.

Answer (score 2):

`$index` will always start at 0, irrespective of your `limitTo` filter. So just use `t` directly in the binding expression.

```
  <body ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="t in getTimes(4) | limitTo:-2">text {{t}} </div>
  </body>

  var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
     $scope.getTimes=function(n){
       return new Array(n);
     };
});
```

Comment: Can we set `limitTo` to `-2` ?

Comment: @PirateX yes we can, it means we will start from the end.  http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_limitto.asp

Comment: I tryed it in code snippet, that's not working... don't know why.

Comment: @WildWidow would you mind to include a jsfiddle because my end nothing comes....do not understand where made the mistake.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar the problem is not with the ng-repeat. It is the problem on how you are creating the array. You are just creating an empty array with length n.  If you have ES6 return new Array(n).fill(0);

Comment: see this url w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ref_limitto_end they can print from 4th position and they use limitTo and negative value.

Comment: tell me what is difference between below two line

`<div ng-repeat="t in [1,2,3,4] | limitTo:-2 track by $index">text {{t}}</div>

and

<div ng-repeat="t in getTimes(4) | limitTo:-2 track by $index">text {{$index+1}} </div>` ?